# Copying matrices

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to copy the matrix and change the new matrix, but don't want to change the initial one. I represent them by arraylist of arraylists. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempMatrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(ArrayList<Integer> row : matrix) {
            for(Integer index : row) {
                tempMatrix.get(row).add(index);
            }
        }
```

Compiler says that it's illegal to use get method for this purpose. What else can I do to copy?

Comment: See the error.... get is used for fetching elements for an index... you are passing objects rather than index which is supposed to be int. Check javadoc  of Arraylist

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy the whole row, saving yourself a lot of trouble:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempMatrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(ArrayList<Integer> row : matrix) {
    tempMatrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(row));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to do just like this, but my initial matrix still changes. Isn't there any way to copy by value, not reference?

Comment: That would be weird, because `new ArrayList<Integer>(row)` should create a brand new array list copying the contents of the `row`. Are you certain the matrix is not being modified elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  for(ArrayList<Integer> row : matrix) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rowList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer index : row) {
            rowList.add(index);
        }
        tempMatrix.add(rowList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the arraylist:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempMatrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(ArrayList<Integer> row : matrix) {
         tempMatrix.add(row.clone());
    }
```

If you use new `Arraylist` then you will have a new `arraylist` indeed but the elements it contains will be a reference to the elements contained in the array that is passed into as constructor argument.